# how to set the x and y cordinates of image formed by imagecreate(width, height) in php

Tags: php, image, coordinates

I have created a sample image in php using

`$image = imagecreate($width , $height);`

In Mozilla firefox, it displays the image in center while in chrome, it displays it of left-middle of the screen...

i want to control the x and y coordinates of this image anywhere in the screen. And in addition can anyone please tell me that what is the dimension of the screen; i,e max(height, width) ... 
please let me know as i am unable to resolve this issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must use HTML (and maybe CSS) to control the display of the image.

Try something like this:

file: `image.html`

```
<style>
    .top_corner_image img {
        border:0;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
</style>
<img class="top_corner_image" src="myimage.php">
```

file: `myimage.php`

```
//put your PHP code to generate the image...
$image = imagecreate($width , $height);
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using at least a class name so that you aren't doing a `position:absolute` on every image that might appear on the document.

Comment: Thank you JeremyJStarcher for ur time, ur solution was very helpful and it did solve the problem.... so, i guess the alignment is possible only via HMLT/CSS, not some build in php function